# Shared Data with multiple Access of spesific activity

Tags: android, sqlite, android-intent

I am new at programming, i confused with this step in my apps development. I have this activity scenario on my android studio. 
A -> B -> C -> B -> D -> B

A is an activity with recycler view,  which  i need to choose one of the list by clicking the list,  the list contain of name and date that i save at my sqlite database. The clicked item contain intent and go to Activity B and pass the data via intent

B is an activity that contain 2 text view,  here is the passed data from A activity will be showed, the name and the date. 
In B also contain 2 button, one will go to activity C and one will go to activity D. 
B is the main activity to do some calculation.

C and D,  both of theese activity have their own mathematical process .  And the result of each activity are double type value that will be passed to activity B.

The problem i am facing are:
1. because the access of B activity  multiple time the passed data from A activity not showed in text view just after go back from activity C.  I tried some solution like onSaveInstanceState with onRestoreInstancestate but the problem would still occur. 
2. What is the best way (i mean i have use the Bundle Intent to pass the data,  but somehow the value cann not be stored? ) to keep the values from activity C and D because i need this 2 values before i could run the main process which is in activity B. In B there is one more button that hanlde the clicked event as the finalization of the matematical process. And then after find the final result of the matematic process the value will be saved to sqlite database based on the name (the showed name on text view )

I really confused,  i know that my understanding still lack,  i hope sombody can enlight me for the best procedure.  Thank you very much

Comment: How do you return from C and D to B?

Answer (score 0):

you should try using classes like Constants with "public static" or Application class to call and save data Globally for the entire project, this way you save a lot of time and project structure is also crystal clear.

Comment: Great, you help me to straight up my understanding and logic. Its worked. Thankss